# Perl print device list

Tags: perl, shell

I have one file which contain device name and it's an output from shell script depending upon region.So region is variable which can be change....e.g 
devicelist=device.region

Now I want to add this device list into email body. For sending email I am using perl script and I have tried below method but its not working...

```
my $file = "$ENV{devicelist}";
open my $fh, '<', $file;
print while (<$fh>);

I am getting this message as :  GLOB(0x11aeea8)
```

Perl script ....

```
my $file = "/tmp/devicelist";open my $fh, '<', $file;print while (<$fh>);
$logger->debug("$logid >> Device names is $deviceinfo");


         $smtp->datasend("Customer Name : $custname\n\n");
         $smtp->datasend("Site Location : $sitename\n\n");
         $smtp->datasend("Region : $region\n\n");
         my $file = "/tmp/devicelist";
         open my $fh, '<', $file;
         print while (<$fh>);
         $smtp->datasend("Device Info : $deviceinfo\n\n"); 1st way
         $smtp->datasend("Device Info perl : $fh\n\n"); 2nd way
```

This request is dealing where i am sending email when there are more than 10 device down and I want to present those 10 devices names. Other information are showing perfectly fine as those are single value stored in variable like region,state ..etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to change

```
print while (<$fh>);
```

to

```
$smtp->datasend($_) while (<$fh>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to load a file's content into a variable?

```
my $file; { local $/; $file = <$fh>; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ... Do you mean I should try like ...  my $file = "/tmp/devicelist";  my $file; { local $/; $file = <$fh>; }  $smtp->datasend("Device Info perl : $fh\n\n");

Comment: `$fh` is a file handle. You can't send a file handle! I presume you want to send the contents of the file, so I showed you how to get the contents of the file. You haven't changed anything in what you posted in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Printing by default goes to standard out, and not to the same place where `$smtp->data send()` is sending string parameters.

I think you just want to re-write your while loop and direct the output correctly; so...

```
print while (<$fh>); #is basically saying:
while (<$fh>) {
  print;
} #but in your smtp block, you don't want to be printing, so write
foreach $fileline (<$fh>) { $smtp->datasend($fileline); }
```

Once you try that, if it's working and therefore this explains what was wrong, then look into slurping the whole file in at once with something like:

```
my $file = "/tmp/devicelist";
open my $fh, '<', $file;
my $filecontents; { local $/; $filecontents = <$fh>; }
$smtp->datasend($filecontents);
```

Other than that, when you say:

```
print while (<$fh>);

I am getting this message as :  GLOB(0x11aeea8)
```

Do you mean, you didn't want to get GLOB(0x11aeea8) or that this is correct output?
If it's the former, I think that's because you wanted to write something like:

```
while (<$fh>) {print $_;}
```